# Changing the versions of the compiler

Tags: solidity, everscale

Maybe someone faced such a problem? I tried to change versions of the compiler, after changing 1 time it accumulates without errors, it crashes again with the same error. Tried 0.64.0, 0.63.0, 0.62.0, 0.61.0, On the last one instead of "[ERROR] undefined" returned "[ERROR] Error: 1". What is the problem?

At the same time, everything passes through ""everdev sol compile"" norms. I don’t really want to switch from locklift, but got stuck due to a mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
npx locklift init --path amazing-everscale-project
cd amazing-everscale-project
npm install --save-dev everdev
npx everdev sol set --compiler 0.64.0 --linker 0.18.4
```

Update locklift.config.ts

```
const config: LockliftConfig = {
  compiler: {
    path: "~/.everdev/solidity/solc",
  },
  linker: {
    lib: "~/.everdev/solidity/stdlib_sol.tvm",
    path: "~/.everdev/solidity/tvm_linker",
  },
...
```

build

```
npx locklift build
```